# How to manually calculate Variance Inflation Factor (VIF)?

Tags: r, variance-inflation-factor

I would like to manually calculate the Variance Inflation Factor (VIF) for mtcars dataset.
When I do it using the function from package I have the following result:

install.packages('car')
library(car)

```
fit <- lm(mtcars[,1] ~ ., mtcars[,-1])
summary(fit)

      cyl      disp        hp      drat        wt      qsec 
15.373833 21.620241  9.832037  3.374620 15.164887  7.527958 
       vs        am      gear      carb 
 4.965873  4.648487  5.357452  7.908747
```

Then I do it one by one for each column:
For the first one `cyl` it's perfectly ok:

```
fit <- lm(mtcars[,2] ~ ., mtcars[,- c(1:2)])
summary(fit)$r.squared 
1/(1-summary(fit)$r.squared)

[1] 15.37383
```

While for `disp` there's a difference already.

```
fit2 <- lm(mtcars[,3] ~ ., mtcars[,- c(1:3)])
summary(fit2)$r.squared 
1/(1-summary(fit2)$r.squared)

[1] 20.08864 # but it must be 21.620241
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula for VIF is:

```
fit2 <- lm(mtcars[,3] ~ ., mtcars[,- c(1,3)])
1/(1-summary(fit2)$r.squared)

21.62024
```

Note that `1:3` means `c(1,2,3)`. We don't want to exclude the second column in the design matrix. Therefore, we should specify `c(1,3)` instead.